# Why is my mantaflow liquid/fluid exploding?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I am making a liquid simulation with mantaflow in blender 2.82.
For some reason my liquid keeps exploding after sometime. I used different resolutions, lowered the inflow, expanded the domain to try too fix this. Does anyone have an explanation why this happens or how to solve this?
[image]

[image: Explosion gif]

Comment: Giving a blender file would be usefull

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have added the blend file.

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6ZV72E32